# Add a number to itself in C++

Tags: c++, multiplication

Which is the simplest way to add a number to itself incrementally until some condition is reached? In the code bellow, we can calculate when an event will occur by simply adding `event_occurence` to itself until we reach `max_events`. I know it can be done with std::IOTA and vectors, but I want it to keep it to the simplest math possible.

My idea was to use: i=1, i * number to be multiplied, for i<=some value, i++. But only the first value gets incremented correctly.

```
int main()
    
    {
        int curent_year = 2021;
        int input_year;
        int event_occurence = 4;
    
        std::cout << "When did you watch your first World Cup?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input_year;
    
        int max_events = (curent_year - input_year) / event_occurence;
        int last_event = input_year + (max_events * event_occurence);
        int next_first_event = input_year + event_occurence;
                
        std::cout << "Next world cup was held in " << next_first_event << "... Meanwhile, another " << max_events << " world cups took place. The last world cup took place in " << last_event <<"." << std::endl;
    
        int i=1;
        int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
                std::cout << "The were also these worlds cups held in the following years: " <<inbetween_events <<std::endl;
        
        }
```

[code above compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV4Y7.png)

Comment: I dont quite get what you are expecting. You never modify inbetween events

Comment: Maybe you should move `inbetween_events` into the `for`-loop and use the `i` index in the calculation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i=1;
    int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;
    for (int i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
            std::cout << "The were also these worlds cups held in the following years: " <<inbetween_events <<std::endl;
    
    }
```

Problem 1:
You're using a local variable (counted in CPU registers) with the same name function variable that is the parent of function for (...). You declare it in there by saying "int i = 1", what means "make new temp variable name i, value = 1)

Move the "calc"

```
int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;
```

inside the function if you want to print out series of numbers (print inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;) , or make it

```
for (; i <= max_events; i++)
```

or

```
for (i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
```

That could work, but I can't test it :P
You could change variables' names, but then it's still pretty ineffective, because you would increment one variable inside a loop, making 2 operations instead of one.

Problem 2:
You also don't increment the "inbetween_events" in the "for" loop.
You ask it to print out that variable "i" times. You initialized that variable as output of arithmetic operation, it wont change its value unless you order it to change it.

Comment: It works if I don t use at all "inbetween_events" variabile:
int i = 1;

 'for (int i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
 std::cout << input_year + i * event_occurence << ", ";'

*When did you watch your first World Cup?
1990
Next world cup was held in 1994... Meanwhile, another 7 world cups took place. The last world cup took place in 2018.
1994, 1998, 2002, 2006, 2010, 2014, 2018,*

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't store instructions and run them later when needed. It runs them right away. So, if you want to compute the in-between events at multiple dates, you need to code it this way:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
            // compute inbetween_events for each value of i
            int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;
            std::cout << "The were also these worlds cups held in the following years: " <<inbetween_events <<std::endl;
    
    }
```

You'll probably want to fix the output with something like:

```
    // output header first
    std::cout << "The were also these worlds cups held in the following years: ";

    for (int i = 1; i <= max_events; i++)
            // compute inbetween_events for each value of i
            int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;
            // output each year with a comma and space
            std::cout << inbetween_events << ", ";
    
    }

    // end the line
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I did paste your code and won't compile.... *double checked everything* I get error "C2065: 'inbetween_events': undeclared identifier". Of course, it will compile if I initialize it twice first as: int inbetween_events; and then `int inbetween_events = input_year + i * event_occurence;` but won't list in beetween events...